# Need help changing out theme based picture on front page, can only be done through host site, not admin panel

Tags: theming, media

I have been taking care of the basic updates on a website for an old friend.  I can do everything through the admin panel except update the main picture on the front page.  You can see it at www.foxviewfarms.com.  It is running Drupal 7.0.  I do know this can only be done through the host site, but I am just a rookie self taught person...I have never done anything like this.

I do understand I should backup before any changes.

So from the host, I found two places that the home image resides.  The first pic here shows my folders.  I went into the public one:

[image: folder list]

Now I pointed to the two places I found the image and I circled its file name.  It would seem to me that I would upload a new picture to each folder, then delete the old picture that resides in the sites/all/foxview/images folder (while keeping it in the themes/foxview/images in case I want to use it again).  The themes/foxview/images folder has the current image and past images, while the sites/all/foxview/images folder has just the new image.

[image]

Am I looking at this right?  Is there anything else I would need to change to update this picture?  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the current image is hardcoded into the template. Best would be create a content type, add an image field, (upload new image), and set that new node page as the home page in the system site settings.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!  I found the image coding in the page.tpl.php file within content/sites/all/themes/foxview. Looking within this finally showed me the coding used to change the homepage picture. It is referencing the files in themes/foxview/images. I switched it to an old picture and then back as a test and it worked.